# Handling Negative Numbers in Hex in DataWeave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule4

I am working on retiring a Python Kafka Consumer to use Mule runtime instead.

I have ran into a blocker with DataWeave and bitwise operators, specifically how to handle negative hex numbers.

Currently, my Kafka/Debezium producer is providing the following value `+PB34g==` which should decode to `-118.458398`

With Python I can use Two's Complement to shift and convert to negative. But, I haven't found a comparable DataWeave solution.

We decode the Base64 value with this function, and then convert to integer with the function below.

```
    # decode the integer
    # and handle negative values
    def _b64_to_int(self, value):
        num = int.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(value), 'big')
        # now check the sign
        # and if negative, take 2's complement
        # TODO: works, but isn't 64-bit safe
        if num & (1 << 31):
            num -= int('1' + '00' * 4, 16)
        #print(f"{value} = {num}")
        return num
```

I can handle this in a Java class, but would prefer to use DataWeave if possible.

```
    # and handle negative values
    def _b64_to_int(self, value):
        num = int.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(value), 'big')
        # now check the sign
        # and if negative, take 2's complement
        # TODO: works, but isn't 64-bit safe
        if num & (1 << 31):
            num -= int('1' + '00' * 4, 16)
        #print(f"{value} = {num}")
        return num
```

I have the following DataWeave to convert from Base64 to a number. I have found [this article](https://syntaxsugar.io/dw-cookbook/#bitwise-math) where custom bitwise functions were created, but they did not handle negative values.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Binaries
fun to_number(b64) = dw::core::Numbers::fromHex(toHex(fromBase64(b64)))
fun to_decimal(num, scale) = to_number(num) as Number / pow(10, scale)
---
to_decimal("+PB34g==", 5)
```

Comment: Please provide some input,  expected output and actual outputs that can be evaluated in both Python and DataWeave to validate that the result is the same. I see that the DataWeave version creates a floating number number while the Python version seems to be only for integers. It doesn't seem that both script will match at all.

Comment: @aled question edited to add your requested changes. Added the additional function in Python, but it does convert to decimal and outputs the expected values at scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I translated the logic from the Python snippet to DataWeave and added the `to_decimal()` function from your DataWeave script to get the expected result.

**WARNING**: I haven't validated the logic nor the mathematics of it.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Binaries
import * from dw::core::Numbers

var leftshift_1_31=fromBinary("10000000000000000000000000000000")
var hex_100000000="0100000000"

fun AND(bin1, bin2) = do {
    var b1=getBinary(bin1, 64)
    var b2=getBinary(bin2, 64)
    ---
    fromBinary(b1 map ($ as Number * b2[$$] as Number) reduce ($$++$))
}

fun getBinary(i: Number, size: Number) = do {
    var b = toBinary(i)
    ---
    dw::core::Strings::leftPad(b, size, '0') splitBy ''
}

fun to_number(b64) = do {
    var result = dw::core::Numbers::fromHex(toHex(fromBase64(b64)))
    ---
    if ((AND(result, leftshift_1_31)==0))
        result 
    else
        result - dw::core::Numbers::fromHex(hex_100000000) 
}

fun to_decimal(num, scale) = to_number(num) as Number / pow(10, scale)
---
to_decimal("+PB34g==", 6)
```

Output:

```json
-118.458398
```